# Need help in selection of FET for transfer gate

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, switching, fet

I was studying the variable potentiometer X9C10x series. They are using a series of fixed resistors and some FETs to select points in this series branch. I need one variable point in my circuit. Can anyone tell me which type of FET I can use here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like a 4016/4066 ic? You’ve not given us much to go on.

Comment: Actually i wanna to use two types of resistances like 40K and 70K. So i want  to make parallel combination to meet my requirement, in which i want to use some FET in one branch to make it on or off.

Comment: Still not telling us much. Be more specific - otherwise we’re just guessing.

Comment: Kartman thanks for your reply.. I have added the picture above. the main idea is  that i need a buck converter which can provide two different voltages(12V and 3.2V) at output. For this i need 66k and 14K resistance controlled by controller at the feedback. so i decided to add the FET as a switch to make it possible. Will this work?

Comment: It would be simpler to switch the value of R7 which would achieve what you want. Why did you not post this schematic first?